# db.create_all() not creating db

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am stuck at trying to create a db following a flask tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr4QMBUPxWo&t=6682s

When I try to run `db.create_all()` after importing db from my project, I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "C:\Users\josep\Market\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py",
> line 868, in create_all
> self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")   File "C:\Users\josep\Market\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py",
> line 839, in _call_for_binds
> engine = self.engines[key]   File "C:\Users\josep\Market\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py",
> line 628, in engines
> app = current_app._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]   File
> "C:\Users\josep\Market\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line
> 513, in _get_current_object
> raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed the current application. To solve this, set up an application
> context with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more
> information.

flashmarket.py
##########################

```
from flask import Flask, render_template 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#__name__ is the name of the current Python module. The app needs to know where it’s located to set up some paths,
# and __name__ is a convenient way to tell it that.
app = Flask(__name__) # creates the Flask instance.
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///flashmarket.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length=1024), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Item {self.name}'
```

Comment: the error tells you what to do.  read the docs.

Comment: How do i set up an application context with app.app_context(). in my code

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/

Comment: The solution to this problem is in the error message - it even tells you the function call to make. Please attempt to solve the problem yourself before coming to Stack Overflow for solutions.